# remove duplicate columns from pandas read excel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The closest answer is the link below.
[how to delete a duplicate column read from excel in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528840/how-to-delete-a-duplicate-column-read-from-excel-in-pandas)

My requirement is slightly different. I have more than 100 columns and the column names can have '.'(dot) in them.Sample dataframe is as follows:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C','A','D. s'])
```

So I cannot truncate based on '.1' or '.2'

Also when I read from excel, the column names are read as A, A.1 and A.2 and so on so even the following command won't work.

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

I want to drop A, A.1 and retain A.2

Please suggest the way forward.

Comment: can you try `df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.replace('\.\d+','').duplicated(keep='last')]` ?

Comment: Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Did you try `df.filter(regex=r'^(?!\w\.[0-9])') ` ?

Comment: @Mayank Porwal, yeah thanks, but it didn't work. Can't figure out why. I am not good with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC , you can first remove the numbers after the dot and then keep only the last duplicates:

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.replace('\.\d+','').duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
In [552]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[552]: 
   A  A.1  A.2  A.3  B  B.1  B.3  B.s
0  1    2    3    4  1    2    1    2
1  2    3    4    5  2    4    4    3

In [554]: df.filter(regex=r'^(?!\w\.[0-9])')                                                                                                                                                                
Out[554]: 
   A  B  B.s
0  1  1    2
1  2  2    3
```